# Passing Array of Objects Down to Child Component and Looping through Array and Passing Down as Props to Second Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope the title kind of sums it up. 
This is my first big React project, so please bear with me.

Basically, I have a productData sheet which contains an array of objects like so:

```
  {
        id: 1,
        name: "Ever Cropped Long Sleeve",
        purpose: 'Designed for Yoga',
        desc_heading: 'Buttery-Soft, Nulu Fabric',
        description: "Designed with our buttery-soft, sweat-wicking Nulu Fabric for a lightweight, barely there experience. With added Lycra fibre, this top offers a four-way stretch and superior shape.",
        fit: 'Tight Fit, Cropped Length',
        material: '81% Nylon, 18% Lycra Elastane',
        care: ['Wash with like colours', 'Machine wash cold', 'Do not bleach', 'Tumble dry low', 'Do not iron', 'Do not dry clean'],
        price: 97.99,
        gender: "women",
        type: "long-sleeve",
        img: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_1?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
        category: "tops",
        highlight: true,
        colors: [{
            colorId: 1,
            colorName: 'Ballet',
            img1: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_1?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
            img2: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_2?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
            img3: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_3?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
            img4: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_4?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
            img5: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_5?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72'
        }, {
            colorId: 2,
            colorName: 'Black',
            img1: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMTS_0001_1?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
            img2: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMTS_0001_2?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
            img3: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMTS_0001_3?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
            img4: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMTS_0001_4?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
            img5: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMTS_0001_5?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72'
        }],
        sizes: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14],
        hover1: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_2?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
        hover2: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_3?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
        hover3: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_4?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72',
        hover4: 'https://images.lululemon.com/is/image/lululemon/LW3DMSS_043612_5?$image_carousel$&wid=1600&op_usm=0.5,2,10,0&fmt=webp&qlt=90,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&iccEmbed=0&printRes=72'
    }
```

I have a Parent (Tops) page that does the following with the data:

```
<div className="Page-PageContent">
                    {Products.map((product) => {
                        if (product.category === "tops") {
                            return (
                                <div className="Page-PageItem">
                                    <PageItem
                                        id={product.id}
                                        name={product.name}
                                        img={product.img}
                                        purpose={product.purpose}
                                        desc_heading={product.desc_heading}
                                        description={product.description}
                                        fit={product.fit}
                                        material={product.material}
                                        care={product.care}
                                        price={product.price}
                                        hover1={product.hover1}
                                        hover2={product.hover2}
                                        hover3={product.hover3}
                                        hover4={product.hover4}
                                        colors={product.colors}
                                        sizes={product.sizes}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                    })}
                </div>
```

Then I have a PageItem component that renders for each product within a specific page category (declared in Tops component):

```
class PageItem extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            show: false,
            color: 1
        };
    }

    changeColor() {
        this.setState({ color: this.props.colors.colorId });
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    handleShow() {
        this.setState({ show: true });
    }

    addItem() {
        inCart.push(this.props.id);
        cartTotal += (this.props.price);
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="item">
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} onClick={this.handleShow}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={this.props.img} />
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{this.props.name}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>
                            {this.props.price}
                        </Card.Text>
                        <button>Quick View</button>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
                <Modal dialogClassName="custom-dialog" show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>{this.props.name}</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <PhotoSlider className="Modal-PhotoSlider" img={this.props.img} hover1={this.props.hover1} hover2={this.props.hover2} hover3={this.props.hover3} hover4={this.props.hover4} />
                                <p>Colors:
                                    {this.props.colors.map((color) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div>
                                            <ColorButton
                                                colorId={color.colorId}
                                                colorName={color.colorName}
                                            />
                                        </div>)
                                })}
                                </p>
                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <p>{this.props.description}</p>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                            Close
          </Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.addItem}>
                            Add to Cart
          </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Within the PageItem, I have a pop-up that displays when someone clicks on an item. It will eventually render different images based on the color selected, but I'm still stuck on trying to loop through each color and create a button for each.

The code I'm using to achieve that is here:

```
{this.props.colors.map((color) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div>
                                            <ColorButton
                                                colorId={color.colorId}
                                                colorName={color.colorName}
                                            />
                                        </div>)
                                })}
```

And then the ColorButton component is like so:

```
const ColorButton = (props) => (
    <div>
        <button key={props.colorId}>
            {props.colorName}
        </button>
    </div>
);
```

It's giving me an error 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined,' and I have no idea how to go about fixing this since I've tried a number of solutions.

I have already tried importing productData into PageItems and saying {Products.colors.map(color) => {...}}, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: There might be a case in which some of your data doesn't have a color property

Comment: @Jagrati ...major fail lol, I didn't add in colors for every product since I was just testing. Adding in colors made it work - thank you!

Comment: Please use debugger next time you face some issues. Its good to debug the issue first.

Comment: @Jagrati what do you recommend using? I was trying to console out what I was passing through, but it kept coming out as undefined. I thought it was a translation issue, like the syntax was just wrong.

Comment: You can use chrome debugger, attach a breakpoint . Please read about that. Also console.log also should be enough.